# Conversion from ArrayList to Collection

Tags: java, collections

I am having difficulty in this conversion. I don't know if there is a syntax error or this is not even possible.

I need to convert from--

```
private static final List<Contact> CONTACTS = Arrays.asList(
        new Contact("text1", "name1"),
        new Contact("text2", "name2"),
        new Contact("text3", "name3"));
```

To--

```
Collection c = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(--?--))
```

--?-- --> (I don't understand what comes here)

By doing this, I intend to avoid UnsupportedOperationException.
Any help appreciated, thanks!

Hey thank you all, i got it!
This worked--
**Solution:**

```
List<? extends Contact> col = new ArrayList<Contact>(CONTACTS);
```

Comment: 1) What does this have to do with GWT?
2) Can you add what you want to do with the `Collection`, and what triggers the UnsupportedOperationException?

Comment: Are you getting `UnsupportedOperationException` when calling remove() on the List?

Comment: I cannot apply CONTACT.remove(index); operation on the ArrayList.

Comment: @Grisle 1)I am using it on the GWT Celltable 2)With Collection I need to remove a row from my List which otherwise is unmodifiable, i.e. I cannot delete a row!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am updating it as an answer I was looking for. Thank you all for your responses!

```
List<? extends Contact> col = new ArrayList<Contact>(CONTACTS);
```

Answer (score 14):

```
public interface List
extends Collection
```

[You don't need to do anything](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html). Or is there some particular operation you need that the  `ArrayList` doesn't support?

Comment: I cannot apply CONTACT.remove(index); operation on the ArrayList.

Comment: @Prince That's because the Collection interface doesn't have a Collection.remove(index) method, only a Collection.remove(Object o) method. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to do anything to perform that conversion, this works:

```
List<Contact> CONTACTS = new ArrayList<String>();
// fill CONTACTS
Collection<Contact> c = CONTACTS;
```

`Collection` is the super-interface of `List`, if an object implements `List` it will also implement `Collection`.

Answer (score 2):

Doing this works:

```
private static final Collection<String> c = new ArrayList<String>(
                                                Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
```

Thus I'd suggest something like:

```
private static final Collection<Contact> = new ArrayList<Contact>(
                       Arrays.asList(new Contact("text1", "name1")
                                     new Contact("text2", "name2")));
```

Comment: Thanks but this will not work for me bcoz i consistently need to update contact from previously updated contact list and this would give me the original list everytime.